# How do I extract a substring from string using a regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am new to regular expressions in Ruby.

The string looks something like `http://www.site.com/media/pool/product_color_purple.jpg` and I am trying to extract from this just the bit which has the colour in it. This can be a variable length, as some of the colours are like `prince_purple.jpg`.

So I have:

```
colour = c.attr('src').match(/(.*)color_(.*).jpg/)
puts "Colour is #{colour}"
```

What colour returns is the string again, instead of the extracted bit, which is the colour. What is going wrong here?

Comment: `match` returns `MatchData` and "mtch[0] is equivalent to the special variable $&, and returns the entire matched string. mtch[1], mtch[2], and so on return the values of the matched backreferences" - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html

Comment: Your link is broken. It's better to show here what you wanted to show.

Answer (score 14):

```
str="http://www.site.com/media/pool/product_color_purple.jpg"
colour = str.match(/color_([^\/.]*).jpg$/)
puts "Colour is #{colour[1]}"
```

You not get "Colour is purple" because match returns MatchData, not string

Answer (score 3):

```
url="http://www.site.com/media/pool/product_color_purple.jpg"
color = url.scan(/color_(.*).jpg/)[0][0]
#=> purple
```

or

```
url="http://www.site.com/media/pool/product_color_purple.jpg"
color = url.match(/color_(.*).jpg/)[1]
#=> purple
```

Answer (score 2):

Without Regexp as an example of another way to do it

```
url="http://www.site.com/media/pool/product_color_purple.jpg"
color = url[url.rindex("_")+1..-1].split(".")[0]
```

For this I would stick with regexp though.

```
color = url.match(/.*_(.*)\./)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>> s = %w(http://www.site.com/media/pool/product_color_purple.jpg http://www.site.com/media/pool/product_color_prince_purple.jpg) 
#=> ["http://www.site.com/media/pool/product_color_purple.jpg", "http://www.site.com/media/pool/product_color_prince_purple.jpg"]
>> s.map { |c| c.match(/\w*_color_(\w+).jpg/)[1] } 
#=> ["purple", "prince_purple"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex.

```
/color_(.*)?.jpg/
```